# How to use dbms_output to display an array of values assigned to a variable?

Tags: arrays, oracle, variables, plsql, dbms-output

I have something like this, but got an error says ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count. I want to see all the values from the "select distinct" statement in the output tab. Anyone can help? thanks!

```
DECLARE
   TYPE v_chks_array IS VARRAY (10) OF VARCHAR2 (50);

   arrSRCs   v_chks_array;
BEGIN
   arrSRCs := v_chks_array ();
   arrSRCs.EXTEND (10);

   SELECT /*+parallel (a,4)*/
         DISTINCT a.src_table
     BULK COLLECT INTO arrSRCs
     FROM hcr_dm.hcr_dm_fact a;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (arrSRCs (10));
END;
```

Comment: Have you verified that there are no more than 10 rows in HCR_DM.HCR_DM_FACT?

Comment: the table has millions of rows. the "select" result can have 0 to 10 records, and there's a potential that there could be more.

Comment: Is there an index on HCR_DR.HCR_DM_FACT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections are not needed here:

```
begin
    for results in
    (
        select /*+ parallel (a,4) */ distinct a.src_table
        from hcr_dm.hcr_dm_fact a;
    ) loop
        dbms_output.put_line(results.src_table);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of VARRAY, you may try a TABLE type collection. You'll have more flexibility with number of records to hold while doing `BULK COLLECT`.

```
Create or replace type v_chks_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (500);
```

More information can be found at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm